# How do I get two different rows for single id for latest updateddatetime

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have below rows. I want to retrieve for single model_instance_id values of CPU and MEM based on latest updateddatetime. If I use "distinct on(model_instance_id) and order by updateddatetime DESC NULLS LAST" I am getting either for CPU or MEM rowa for single instance. I want both.

```
model_instance_id | metric_name |    metric_value    |      updateddatetime

           1059971 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 12:58:38.461286
           1059971 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 12:38:55.77642
           1059971 | MEM         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 12:03:33.411069
           1059971 | MEM         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 11:43:44.102632
           1059990 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 11:23:54.731535
           1059990 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 11:04:11.673082
           1059990 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 10:44:30.661532
           1059990 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 10:24:44.181107
           1059990 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 10:04:49.792651
           1059990 | MEM         | 0.8048095703125    | 2023-03-24 12:58:38.492705
           1059990 | MEM         | 0.8048095703125    | 2023-03-24 12:38:55.823345
           1059990 | MEM         | 0.8048095703125    | 2023-03-24 12:03:33.473615
           1059990 | MEM         | 0.8048095703125    | 2023-03-24 11:43:44.118206
           1059990 | MEM         | 0.8048095703125    | 2023-03-24 11:23:54.794035
```

I tried below

```
select DISTINCT ON ("model_instance_id")model_instance_id, model_manager_id,metric_name,metric_value,mim.updateddatetime 
from criml.model_instance_metrics 
where nd  mim.metric_name in ('CPU','MEM') 
order by model_instance_id,metric_name,mim.updateddatetime DESC NULLS LAST;
```

But it gives only for either CPU or MEM as I used distinct. I had to use distinct since ids are repeated multiple times for different datetimes.

I want like below WHERE updatedatetine is the latest one

```
model_instance_id | metric_name |    metric_value    |      updateddatetime
-------------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------
           1059971 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 12:58:38.461286
           1059971 | MEM         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 12:38:55.776426
           1059990 | CPU         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 11:43:44.102632
           1059990 | MEM         | 3                  | 2023-03-24 11:23:54.731535
```

Comment: After looking at your expected output; You have not provided correct sample data for table

And also the `expected sample output` is not correct as per explanation

Comment: Please let me; if the solution provided below helps

Comment: Use distinct on across multiple columns: `distinct on(model_instance_id,metric_name)`.

Comment: this also gave me the expected output.thanks dint expect solution would be this simple   @Belayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get two different rows for single id for latest
> updateddatetime

You can use row_number() in postgresql to achieve the same.

Here is the demo using [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/9wiYmOg1).

```
SELECT model_instance_id, metric_name, metric_value, updateddatetime
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY model_instance_id, metric_name ORDER BY updateddatetime DESC) AS rn
  FROM model_instance_metrics
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

With your provided sample data;

It shall give you output as :

```
model_instance_id   metric_name   metric_value      updateddatetime
1059971             CPU           3                 2023-03-24 12:58:38.461286
1059971             MEM           3                 2023-03-24 12:03:33.411069
1059990             CPU           3                 2023-03-24 11:23:54.731535
1059990             MEM           0.8048095703125   2023-03-24 12:58:38.492705
```

Explanation based on comment :

> I want to know what role does rn play in query.why rn =1 condition is
> given in above query:

In this query we have created the `rn` column using a window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY model_instance_id, metric_name ORDER BY updateddatetime DESC)`.
The function will assign a unique sequential number to each row within a partition of the result set defined by `model_instance_id` and `metric_name`,
based on the descending order of the `updateddatetime`.

`rn` column is to identify the most recent row for each combination  of `model_instance_id` and `metric_name`. As we sorting the rows by `updateddatetime` in descending order,
The most recent row for each combination will have a value of 1 in the `rn` column.

So, we are using `WHERE rn = 1` to filter the result set to include only the most recent row for each combination of `model_instance_id` and `metric_name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot tushar for understanding the problem statement.Above solution actually worked. But i want to know what role does rn play in query.why rn =1  condition is given in above query

Comment: @snehapriyakatikala; I have updated the answer with explanation;
Can you accept it / upvote it; if it has solved your original problem and follow-up questions?